# Вопрос к CSS3

Tags: css3

У меня есть три  вложенных дива
Вопрос: Как задать селектор к id="2" по месту в DOM, не затрагивая id="3"
Вот так пробывал,

```
   #wrapper_toltip_output div
```

, но оно придает и id="3" свои стили

```
   <div id="1">
        <div id="2">
             <div id="3">
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ

```
#wrapper_toltip_output > div
```